# Error installing selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x

Getting this error when running `pip install -U selenium`. Mid way through the script, it gets the following SyntaxError:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "C:\Python32\Scripts\build\rdflib\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from rdflib import __version__
      File "rdflib\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
        from rdflib.term import URIRef, BNode, Literal, Variable
      File "rdflib\term.py", line 367
        except TypeError, te:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "C:\Python32\Scripts\build\rdflib\setup.py", line 6, in <module>

    from rdflib import __version__

  File "rdflib\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>

    from rdflib.term import URIRef, BNode, Literal, Variable

  File "rdflib\term.py", line 367

    except TypeError, te:

                    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

Since it is a Syntax Error, I assume it is a python version problem, I'm running 3.2.2. 
Pip did come with a pip-3.2.exe file, which I tried to run. But I got the same error. I'm pretty new to Python so it might be something simple.

And how can it be a syntaxError? pip is an already made program.

Running Win7, Python 3.2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium does not support Python 3. Use Python 2.7 instead.

Sadly, almost all Python software requires Python 2.x.

[Update]
Selenium supports Python 3.x now.

Comment: Once you install Python2, run `pip2` instead of `pip`.

Comment: I've noticed that everywhere I look people are always talking about 2.x, never about 3.x. Well I used the easy_install.exe instead of pip and it worked (I think?). I thought Python was supposed to be easy. I guess the easiness of the languages must be balanced by the hardness of installation. -_-

Comment: Does it hold true even now. That Selenium does not work with Py3.x?